# Cache pattern with callbacks

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, coffeescript

I have a class that handles data. Other classes can give it their values and the data class will populate them.

It looks like this:

```
class Data

  constructor : ->
    @products = null

  populateProducts : (callback)=>
    ajaxCall (data)=>
      @products = data
      callback()

  allProducts : (list)=>
    if @products?
      list = @products
    else
      @populateProducts => allProducts list
```

The problem I am facing is that every method I add will have to check if products exists. So I am looking into ways to make that part of the code reusable.

One way I tried was the following:

```
  productsCheck : (callback)=>
    if @products?
      callback()
    else
      @populateProducts => products callback
```

Using this method I could simplify allProducts:

```
 allProducts : (list)=>
     @productsCheck => list = @products
```

In the end I am looking for technique that does: "if products don't exists populate them from the database". I was maybe thinking that this might be a known pattern so if that is the case information about it is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're loading `@products` asynchronously, and every method on the object has to (potentially) wait for `@products` to load, every method on the object is asynchronous and needs to return its result to a callback. There's no way around this; you can't make asynchronous JS code synchronous. `allProducts` can't just return a value.

Here's what you should do: First, change `populateProducts` so it won't make an Ajax call if it doesn't have to:

```
populateProducts : (callback) =>
  if @products?
    callback()
  else ajaxCall (data) =>
    @products = data
    callback()
```

Then just start each method that uses `@products` with a call to `@populateProducts`, like so:

```
allProducts : (callback) =>
  @populateProducts =>
    callback @products

firstProduct: (callback) =>
  @populateProducts =>
    callback @products[0]

# ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Underscore has the concept of [`_.memoize`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#memoize)

Which will cache the result of a function call to an id (i.e. the first argument).

[Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is an easy pattern to implement.

```
var memoize = function _memoize(f) {
  var cache = {};
  return function _intercept(arg) {
    if (cache[arg]) return cache[arg];
    return (cache[arg] = f.apply(this, arguments));
  }
};
```

You have to adjust this pattern to make it work asynchronously with callbacks.

For complete-ness here is the `_.memoize` code :

```
_.memoize = function(func, hasher) {
  var memo = {};
  hasher || (hasher = _.identity);
  return function() {
    var key = hasher.apply(this, arguments);
    return hasOwnProperty.call(memo, key) ? memo[key] : (memo[key] = func.apply(this, arguments));
  };
};
```

Underscore seems to accept a `hasher` as a second argument which will generate a unique key based on the arguments. (the default is underscore identity function).

It also seems to use `hasOwnProperty` so you can use annoying keys like `toString` and `valueOf` which will flag truthy on a property check.

Comment: Ah, that's great going to look into that. Lets just hope I never have to pronounce that name in public.